# ios 8 box shadow on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, css, viewport, meta, device-width

I have a display problem with the box shadow property specifically on the iPhone 6 plus.
If I add the meta tag `width=device-width`, the following box shadow isn't displayed at all:

`-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #a8a8a8;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 5px #a8a8a8;`

If I don't use the meta tag, box shadows "magically" disappear if you zoom into the page. You can comprehend this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/b6aaq57z/3/

This seems to be a specific iPhone 6 plus bug. On older iPhone Versions running the same iOS Version (8.0.2), the box shadows are working properly.

Is there anyone with a solution?

Comment: Try: -webkit-appearance: none; is only a comment.

Comment: I have the same problem on iPhone 5. Box shadow is visible with no `width=device-width`, but disappears when screen is zoomed in.

Answer (score 19):

You can add **border-radius:1px** to the div. It fixes the box-shadow issue in iphone 6+ and other retina devices

```
.box-shadow{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.25em 0.25em #a8a8a8;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.25em 0.25em #a8a8a8;
 border-radius:1px;}
```

Comment: Nice workaround. I got it working on iPhone 6 plus using a border-radius: 0.1px; so it has almost no visible impact.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `-webkit-apperance: none;`

You can add this to your global reset to eliminate all issues with this. I use:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

I also have my box-sizing reset in there as well.